# File Pointers in assembly language

Tags: assembly

I am not able to move pointers in assembly language.I am trying to move my pointer to 4th position in a file and then read and display 3 bytes.
This is my code-

```
.model tiny
.data
fil1    db      'testing.txt',0
dat1    db      100 dup('$')
dat2    db      100 dup('$')
.code
.startup
        mov     al,02h
        lea     dx,fil1
        mov     ah,3dh
        int     21h

        mov     bx,ax
        mov     al,00
        mov     cx,00
        mov     dx,04
        mov     ah,42h
        int     21h

        mov     bx,ax
        lea     dx,dat2
        mov     cx,3
        mov     ah,3fh
        int     21h
        mov     ah,09h
        lea     dx,dat2
        int     21h



        mov     ah,3eh
        int     21h
.exit
end
```

This does not display anything on console.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple remove the last "mov bx,ax" instruction. Because the LSEEK function(42h) returns in DX:AX the new file position in bytes from start of file. The first "mov bx,ax" instruction already moved the file handle into BX and BX remained untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `mov bx,ax` (the one right before `lea dx,dat2`) is incorrect, because `ax` no longer contains the file handle at that point. Since `bx` already contains the file handle there you can simply remove that `mov`.

Comment: Thanks it worked.But I have another question.Suppose if I want to move the pointer from backward say 4th last position of the file.How can I do this.I tried doing it by`mov al,2` and  `mov dx,-4` but it did not work

Comment: Use the sub intstruction for to substract the content of a register.

Comment: I tried even that.`mov al,2`,`mov cx,0`,`mov dx,0` and then later `sub ax,4` but even this didnt work

Comment: For to set the file position to 4th last position use .mov al,2,mov cx,0,mov dx,4